# "I studied not math but English yesterday." or "I didn't study math but English yesterday."

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence below grammatically correct?
"I studied not math but English yesterday."

Or should I write "I didn't study math but English yesterday."?

Comment: Both of your sentences are grammatically correct, but are very unnatural.  A normal English version might be: "I studied English, not math, yesterday" or if you want to keep "math" at the front: "I didn't study math yesterday; I studied English"

Comment: @Juhasz Or if it was a matter of your own choice you could say "I studied English rather than Maths yesterday".

Answer (score 1):

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct, but are very unnatural. A normal English version might be: "I studied English, not math, yesterday" or if you want to keep "math" at the front: "I didn't study math yesterday; I studied English"